# Set multiple div height based on a defined div

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I make `<div A>` and `<div C>` to have same height as `<div B>` in javascript/jquery?

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="divA"></div>
  <div id="divB"></div>
  <div id="divC"></div>
</div>

<script>
 $('#divA').css('height', $('#divB').innerHeight());
 $('#divC').css('height', $('#divB').innerHeight());
</script>
```

[image: enter code here]

Comment: Any reason you don't want to use flex boxes?

Comment: thanks. I'd rather stick with @guest271314 's answer. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
$("#divA, #divC").height($("#divB").height());
```

```js
$("#divA, #divC").height($("#divB").height());
```

```css
#divA, #divC {
  height: 50px;
  width:50px;
  background:gold;
}

#divB {
  height: 100px;
  width:50px;
  background:red;
}

div {
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="divA"></div>
  <div id="divB"></div>
  <div id="divC"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this demo :  [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/stanze/sL403xr7/)

```
var selDivB = $('#divB').height();
$('#divA, #divC').height(selDivB);
```